# Localhost printing code, why?

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

I have problem with localhost server. Server printing code in the screen after ->.
e.g:
I have code:

```
function check_it($email, $password, $mysqli) {

       if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) { 
          $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
```

And after -> I have code in webpage. Why localhost printing code? I tryed other wamp servers platforms, but nothing changed... Now I'm using XAMPP.
Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: View the source code of your page. I bet there's a lot more of it in there.

Comment: Does it work with XAMPP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened when you tried other servers?

Are you putting this in an `echo` statement?

Is this block of code accidentally appearing after or before `<?php ?>` ? Can you post the entire code here?

Comment: Oh my... I forgot to write php, I jus wrote <?... But why then localhost printing code? When I upload page to hosting is everything good

Comment: `<?` alone will not work. I am not sure if PHP on your webhost is automatically appending `<?php ?>` tags, it might just be. But you need to note that every bit of php code needs to be enclosed within `<?php ?>` tags. Your localhost is either running a different version of PHP, or doesn't have functionality to include the tags automatically.

Comment: @edvinedi, your host may have [short tags enabled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag). Most developers seem to recommend not using short tags these days.